# How to add a numerical value for a char in Java

Tags: java, char, ascii

I have this code where I want to add the value 97 for a char variable, but instead to obtain, according with ASCII table, the final number 98 for the letter 'b' the output is 205.

What is wrong in my code?

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char result;
        String input = "blablab";

        result = charCounter(input);

    }

    private static char charCounter(String input) {

        int[] array = new int[26];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char ch = input.charAt(i);

            array[ch - 97]++;

        }

        int max = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (array[i] > max) {
                max = array[i];
                char frequent = input.charAt(i);

                System.out.println(frequent + 97);

            }

        }

        return 45;
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In your second `for` loop, what makes you think `i` should be an index into the input string? E.g., if I enter `f`, I'm entering a one-character string. But `array` is 26 entries long, and your loop goes well past that point, so `input.charAt(i)` will fail.

Comment: because I obtain the more frequent letter 'l'

Comment: No, you don't. Think the logic through more carefully. Maybe even draw the array and input string out on paper to understand what `i` will do in that second loop if the input string is just `f`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: oh oh, are you right, the output is: `String index out of range: 5`

Comment: the more letter should be 'b' three times rather than 'I' two times.

Comment: @cainiaofei: yes I corrected, too many numbers and  indices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
System.out.println(frequent + 97);
```

with

```
System.out.println((char)(i + 97));
```

because

```
char + Integer = Integer
```

so you have to convert it to `char`
and the `ascii` of *corresponding char* should be

```
i + 97
```

rather than

```
frequent + 97
```

Comment: `Integer` => `int`

Comment: @cainiaofei: sounds good, now the code works properly.  In this way I fix even the problem of a single letter as input.
Thank you